# What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've gotten many errors in my code that I believe has been the result of mix-ups between `GuildMembers` and `Users`. Can someone explain the difference?

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();

// TypeError: user.kick() is not a function
user.kick({ reason: 'spamming' });

// TypeError: user.ban() is not a function
user.ban({ reason: 'DM Advertising' });

// TypeError: message.author.hasPermission() is not a function
if (!message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return;

console.log(user.displayName); // undefined

// TypeError: message.member.createdAt() is not a function
embed.addField('Account Created', message.member.createdAt());

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
 console.log(`${newMember.tag} was updated`); // 'undefined was updated'
});

if (message.member.bot) return; // undefined

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
user.roles.add(newRole)

const target = message.client.users.cache.get(args[0])
console.log(target.displayName) // undefined
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### From [Official Discord.js Guide - Common Questions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-create-a-restart-command):

> A lot of users get confused as to what the difference between `Users` and `GuildMembers` is. The simple answer is that a `User` represents a global Discord user and a `GuildMember` represents a Discord user on a specific server. That means only `GuildMembers` can have permissions, roles, and nicknames, for example, because all of these things are server-bound information that could be different on each server that user is in.

---

Many errors in the code in question occur because you are trying to call a guild specific function on a global user. For example, [`GuildMember.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) and [`GuildMember.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban). A very common mistake that leads to this is using the [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) collection. As the name suggests, this returns a collection of *`Users`*.

If you simply want, for example, the mentioned user's avatar, or maybe they're username and discriminator, it would work out fine. But it will lead to errors if you ever try to, for example, try to get the date they joined your server using [`GuildMember.joinedAt()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt)

Luckily, there are many easy ways to circumvent this issue. For example, using [`MessageMentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) (returns a collection of `GuildMembers`) instead of `MessageMentions.users`

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
member.ban() // no error here!
```

Another common workaround is using the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) method, which accepts a `User` object *or* ID!

```js
const user = client.user // get the user object
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID') // get the guild object

const member = guild.member(user) // convert the User object to a GuildMember!
```

Other useful tricks to easily convert `Users` to `GuildMembers` include:

- Using [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) instead of [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)
- Using [`guild.members.cache.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) instead of [`client.users.cache.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache)
- Using [`guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead of [`client.users.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)
- Using [`presence.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=member) instead of [`presence.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=user)

It's also very useful to remember if specific event parameters provide `Users` or `GuildMembers`. For example, both [`guildMemberAdd()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) and [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) pass `GuildMembers`, but [`messageReactionAdd()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd), [`guildBanAdd()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd), and [`typingStart()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-typingStart) all pass `Users`.

---

While many `GuildMember` properties and methods are not available for a `User`, the same is true the other way around. For example, `GuildMember.tag` does not exist. However, converting a `GuildMember` to a `User` is *much* easier than converting a `User` to a `GuildMember`. This is because of [`GuildMember.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user):

> The user that this guild member instance represents

So, although `GuildMember.tag` will return `undefined`, *`GuildMember.user.tag`* will not!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Lioness100's answer, the following no longer seems to work

```
const member = guild.member(user);
```

Instead you can use:

```
const member = guild.members.fetch(user);
```

This returns a promise so don't forget to deal with that accordingly