# My avatar command doesn't show the avatar. Only thing shown is a blank embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My code is as shown:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '>pfp') {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
  const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setImage(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
   .setColor('#0099ff');
  message.channel.send(embed);
 }
});
```

I'm a starter to Discord.js so an explanation would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object, and it has no `displayAvatarURL` property, nor method. You're looking for [`Message.member.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), which is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, containing the [`displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) method.

*(I applaud you for using `displayAvatarURL` instead of `avatarURL` because it returns the default avatar instead of `undefined` if the user does not have an avatar.)*

---

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '>pfp') {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
   // You can use message.author instead of message.member.user.
   .setColor('#0099ff');
  message.channel.send(embed);
 }
});
```

Comment: Nope. Still blank sadly

Comment: Thanks! It works... Is there any way to make it bigger though?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can use `MessageEmbed.setImage()` instead, but that'll make the image even smaller.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) is a function, not a property. Second of all, [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). However, `displayAvatarURL` only works on a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js/63979077#63979077) for more details). Instead, use [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author):

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
 .setColor('#0099ff');
```