# verify command in a specific channel, and a specific message without prefix

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm basically trying to code something where you need to send a message to a specific channel, and a specific message to send to get a specific role, basically like verifying as such but without the prefix but an error keeps popping up and i cant get rid of it.

The script i am trying to fix:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
if(message.channel.id === '753928667427635230'){
        if(message.content == 'test'){
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find('757964609222344744')
        let member = message.author.id
        member.roles.add(role)
        message.channel.send('script works')
    }
}
```

The error code below:

```
(node:14284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fn is not a function
at Map.find (C:\Users\haxor\Desktop\HardWareProject\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:161:17)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\haxor\Desktop\HardWareProject\main.js:37:50)
at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\haxor\Desktop\HardWareProject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\haxor\Desktop\HardWareProject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

my entire script:

```
      const Discord = require('discord.js')
      const bot = new Discord.Client()
      const botsettings = require('./botsettings.json')
      const fs = require('fs')

            bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
            bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

            fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);

            let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js');
            if(jsfile.length <= 0){
            console.log('Commands aren\'t found!');
            return;
    }

            jsfile.forEach((f) => {
            let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
            console.log(`${f} loaded!`)
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);

            props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
        })
    })
})

            bot.on("ready", async () => {
            console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.username}`);
            bot.user.setActivity(`HardLies`, {type: 'WATCHING' });
})
            // Where the current error is at
            bot.on("message", async message => {
            if(message.channel.id === '753928667427635230'){
            if(message.content == 'test'){
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find('757964609222344744')
            let member = message.author.id
            member.roles.add(role)
            message.channel.send('script works')
    }
}

            if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
            if(message.author.bot) return;

            let prefix = botsettings.prefix;

            if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
            let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
            let cmd;
            cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            let command;
            let commandFile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
            if(commandFile) commandFile.run(bot, message, args);

            if(bot.commands.has(cmd)){
            command = bot.commands.get(cmd);
    } else if(bot.aliases.has(cmd)){
            command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
}
try {
            command.run(bot, message, args);
} catch (e){
            return;
}

});

            bot.login(botsettings.token);
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to close and if statement with a bracket instead of a brace on the  last line there.

Comment: oh it was just something i did wrong while making this

Comment: Fn is not used at all in your code, which makes me wonder that the error doesn't come from the code you provided. Could you provide the entire code?

Comment: Use `.get()` instead of `.find()` for IDs

Answer (score 0):

The error "fn is not a function" is when you used `.find(value)` but this is an incorrect use. Try `.find(u => u.id ==== ID)` (for members `.find(m => m.user.id === ID)` or a better way you can just use `.get(ID)`

Second, you are trying to add a role to a `User` object. Wich is not possible. You'll have to use a `GuildMember` object [(the difference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js) So instead use :

```js
const user = message.member
```

And last, to add a role you'l have to use `cache` before the add function

```js
member.roles.cache.add(role)
```

Your code should look list :

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {
if(message.channel.id === '753928667427635230'){
        if(message.content == 'test'){
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('757964609222344744')
        let member = message.author.id
        member.roles.cache.add(role)
        message.channel.send('script works')
    }
}
```