# filter reactions from specific roles or permissions

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make the command work only if the user who reacts has a specific role or permission

I know I should use a filter but, I don't know-how
this is the filter that I use

```
  const approveFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a user has a role, you can use the [`GuildMemberRoleManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) collection. To check if the user has a permission, you can use the [`GuildMember.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) method.

Both of these require a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object, although the [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorFilter) function passes a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) as the parameter (please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js/63979077#63979077) to learn the difference). So, the first step will be to convert the `User` to a `GuildMember` using the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) function.

Luckily, we can access the guild object from the [`reaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) parameter!

```js
const approveFilter = (reaction, user) =>
 reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && // check emoji name
 reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.has('Role ID') && // check if they have a role
 reaction.message.guild.member(user).hasPermission('Permission Flag'); // check if they have a permission
```