# Discord specific roles required for adding a reaction to a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'specific role')

  if (reaction.emoji.id == '759643335043448834' && reaction.author.roles.has(role.id))
  return
  else await reaction.message.delete({timeout:2500})
  
});
```

so right now this is giving me a error saying guild is not defined. I want it to remove a specific custom emoji when a user doesn't have a specific role I am kind of confused what to do anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. The first one, obviously, is that `guild` is not defined. Luckily, [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) has a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message) property, which has a [`guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) property.

```js
const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(
 (role) => role.name === 'specific role'
);
```

First of all, `reaction` doesn't have an `author` property. Even if it did, it would return a `User` object, which you can't access roles from. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js/63979077#63979077) to see the difference. Instead, you should use the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) function.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
 const guild = reaction.message.guild;
 const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'specific role');

 if (
  reaction.emoji.id == '759643335043448834' &&
  guild.member(user).roles.has(role.id)
 )
  return;

 reaction.message.delete({ timeout: 2500 });
});
```

Comment: I think you might have accidentally added an "s". It's `Guild.member()`, not `Guild.members()`

Comment: well that didn't fix it