# Discord.js TypeError: member.kick is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

The title says it all... I have a problem with my kick command. I don't know why. Never seen anything like this. I've tried reinstalling `Discord.js` but I had no luck.

**Code:**

```
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    aliases: [],
    run: async (message, args, client) => {



        if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
            message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use that command.");

          } else {
        
            let member = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);

       
                } else {
                    await member.kick();
                    console.log(`${message.author.username} kicked ${member} from ${message.guild.name} for ${reason}. Rest In Peace...`);
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                       // kick successful embed
                    });
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

All the rest were error embeds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `kick()` on the wrong object. You need to get the member from the guild first. From the Discord.js docs it should be:

```
 // this returns the user mentioned in the message
 let member = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
 if (member) {
   // this gets the member from the user
   const user = message.guild.member(member);
   if (user) {
     user.kick('user was being bad')
       .then(() => { message.reply('Successfully kicked.' })
       .catch(err => { // handle error });
   }
 }
```

Note: I used the variable names you have in your snippet but I suggest flipping `member` and `user`. Here's the example from the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/moderation