# make an autorole for discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I wanna make my bot give automatically role when my friends join for first time to my server: I have tried this one *my VPS node version: 12.19.0v*:?

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
console.log('User @' + member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');
var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Newbie")
let user = member.user
user.roles.add(role);
});
```

but nothing is working ! help me pls

Comment: Does the console.log() writes on console?

Comment: what do you mean ? it what in my visual: https://prnt.sc/v7z2m8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js) You should be using [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member)

Comment: Also, "does not work" is not sufficient information to provide to receive help. Do you get any errors?

Comment: literally without any errors just nothing happening when my friend is join !

Comment: Does it log `User @Someone#0000 has joined the server`?

Comment: No it doesn't say something my log only when i run it say: bot is online

Answer (score 1):

Discord is now enforcing privileged intents. The `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent is required to receive events such as `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberUpdate`.

To learn how intents work and how to use them, check out [discord.js' detailed guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents).

Also, as stated in the comments, you need to use `message.member` instead of `message.user`

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the difference between Members and Users. A user represents a Discord account, a member represents a user being in a server. So for example to get someone's tag, you need to do `user.tag`, `member.tag` wouldn't work. It's the same with nicknames, `user.displayName` woudln't work, because a user is an account, a member is a user in a server. You'd do `member.displayName` instead.

Anyway, where you put

```
let user = member.user
user.roles.add(role);
```

it should be replaced with

```
member.roles.add(role);
```

and that should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: i tried this one before doesn't work as well i don't receive when someone join to my server on log too !