# why does discord.js not let me do guild.members.fetch()?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When I try and run `membermanager.fetch();` ([documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)), I get the error `Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.`

I have quite a good internet connection and I've tried giving it more time. This happens both on my test server with about 10 members and the server its intended for with about 30. `membermanager.cache` doesn't suffice for my use case. It's not a temporary problem as this was also happening yesterday. My discord.js version is `12.4.1` and I updated it this morning. If it helps the bot is written in typescript.

I've noticed it works if I pass the `query` parameter as a non-empty string or `user` as an array of user ids, but I assume the discord.js source code is calling a different method entirely.

This has properly left me stumped. If you could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent enabled?

Comment: @Lioness100 how do I enable that?

Comment: Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556167/make-an-autorole-for-discord-js-v12)

Comment: @Lioness100 you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

Turns out I didn't have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent set.
A quick fix from this:

```
import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";
export const client: Client = new Client();
```

to something that included intents:

```
import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";
let intents = new Intents(Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED);
intents.add('GUILD_MEMBERS');
export const client: Client = new Client({ ws: {intents: intents} });
```

and a fix in the discord developer portal. That's all it needed.

Comment: Thanks! Mine wasn't working because I didn't have ALL intents enabled. Only GUILD_MEMBERS. This was super helpful.