# Move mentioned user from a voice channel to another (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot move users between channels automatically, to make a "cool-looking effect". For example, a user is in channel "1" and the bot has to move him to channel "2", then channel "3" etc.

**The problem**

> I can't really find a way to move a mentioned user to another channel. I know
> this `member.voice.setChannel()` is used to, well, move a user into a
> specified channel but it doesn't work.

**What I tried**

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.author.bot) {
    if(message.content.startsWith('.move')) {
      const member = message.mentions.users.first();
      const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("770310636726517760"); //spazio1
      member.voice.setChannel(channel)
    }
  }});
```

I tried the code above but it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined`.

I searched online for hours and didn't find anything that could help me. I only found a piece of code that would move every user to a specified user's voice chat. I tried to adapt that to my needs, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just for future reference, `Cannot read property x of undefined` errors do not mean `x` is undefined or not working. It means what it was *called on* is undefined. In this case, `member.voice`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js) (`message.mentions.users.first()` should be `message.mentions.members.first()`)