# How to check the role of a reacting member discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm fairly new to discord.js and have recently ran into a problem with a section of my code.

```js
if (reaction.message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Goof Archivist ")) {
```

This section is supposed to check if a reacting member has the role "Goof Archivist ". But instead checks the role of the person that sent the message that is being reacted to. if that makes sense. any help would be appreciated.

[image: My code]

Comment: Is this in a `messageReactionAdd` event?

Comment: Umm yes sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) event, the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) that reacted, and the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) method.

`Guild.member()` can convert a global user object to a guildmember object in which you can see the roles of. To learn the difference between the two, check out [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js).

```js
if (
 reaction.message.guild
  .member(user)
  .roles.cache.some((role) => role.name == 'Goof Archivist ')
)
```