# User-info Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Am trying to do the userinfo command for the most part I have most of the fields down but I can't seem to get status field down it says am offline when am online and permissions no matter what I try it doesn't send it sends me a error in the terminal saying undefined and for the nickname field it gives me undefined in the embed

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
name: 'user',
description: 'Get your or someone else\'s user info',
aliases: ['u',],
cooldown: 2,
execute(message) {
    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(message.author.username)
            .addField('Created',message.author.createdAt)
            .addField('ID',message.author.id)
            .addField('Nickname',message.author.nickname, true)
            .addField("Status",`${ message.author.presence.status}`, true)
            .addField('Joined current server on', message.member.joinedAt)
            .addField('Currently in', message.guild.name)
            .addField('Roles', `<@&${message.guild.member(message.author)._roles.join('> <@&')}>`, true)
            .addField('Permissions',`${message.author.permissions}` )
            .addField('Status',message.author.presence.status)
            .setColor(0x00ffff)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }))
            .setFooter(`Requested By:${message.author.username}`)
            .setTimestamp();
        return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this code. First of all, [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), which does not have a `nickname`. Since nicknames can be modified per server, you're looking for a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

- [Learn more about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Also, `GuildMember.nickname` will return undefined if the `GuildMember` doesn't actually have a nickname. There are a few ways you can fix it. You can either use `GuildMember.displayName`, which will try to display the nickname but will display the username if none is found, or you could simply handle it with the logical OR operator `||`

```js
// method 1:
.addField('Nickname', message.author.displayName, true)

// method 2:
.addField('Nickname', message.author.nickname || 'This user has no nickname', true)
```

Speaking of `GuildMembers` and `Users`, you are using a very overcomplicated way to get the `GuildMember` instance of the author at this line:

```js
message.guild.member(message.author);
```

There's actually an easier way to use this: [`Message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member). It's the same thing as `Message.author`, but returns a `GuildMember`. Also, I'm not sure why you're using the `_roles` getter instead of the much more efficient `roles`.

You have the same problems with `message.author.permissions`, as permissions are modified per guild and do not have one global value. Even then, it's going to return `[object Object]`. And even if it didn't, it would probably return a bitfield representation which would not be legable by the average discord user.

Instead, you should use the [`Permissions.toArray()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=toArray) method, which will return an array of bitfield *names* based on the bits available (all of the member's permissions). It might look a bit like this:

```js
[
 CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE,
 ADD_REACTIONS,
 STREAM,
 VIEW_CHANNEL,
 SEND_MESSAGES,
 EMBED_LINKS,
 ATTACH_FILES,
 READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY,
 USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS,
 CONNECT,
 SPEAK,
 USE_VAD,
 CHANGE_NICKNAME,
];
```

You can use `Array.prototype.join()` to join these elements by a line break, or a comma and space, etc.

Also, you shouldn't be using template literals unless you want to add a variable to a string with other characters/template literals, or you need to coerce the variable's data type to string. `message.author.presence.status` for example, is *already* a string, so:

```
- `${ message.author.presence.status}`
+ message.author.presence.status
```

[`Presence.status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status) is returning 'offline' because [you don't have the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)