# Moving a mentioned user into a specific voice channel

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to move the tagged user into the voice channel using the channel ID. I saw someone use .setUserChannel but it tells me that it isn't a function. Can someone tell me what I need to fix please :)

```
    if(command === 'ping'){
    message.channel.send('pong');
} else if (command === 'abuse'){
            //const AbuseTown = client.channel.cache.get(760535995329282161);
            const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
            message.channel.send(`You want to abuse: ${taggedUser.username}`);
            taggedUser.setVoiceChannel('776202269569712168');
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object, not the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object. Learn more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

```js
// change:
const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

// to:
const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Second of all, [`GuildMember.setVoiceChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel) is an outdated function, so it won't work if you're using v12.x. Instead, use [`VoiceState.setChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel).

```js
const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();
message.channel.send(`You want to abuse: ${taggedUser.username}`);
taggedUser.voice.setChannel('776202269569712168');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i've got it working now. Have a good day :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem, as it will be easier to find for others in the future who have the same issue.