# kick command is not working and getting an error when try kicking an admin, how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im adding moderation commands into my bot, but I dont want people to be able to kick admins, so i added some code, but it did not work well, when i do `,kick` it tell me Please specify a member to kick, perfect, when i do `,kick @[user]` it kicks the user, but when i try kicking an admin it gives me an error message saying `Cannot read property 'has' of undefined` here is the code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: '[DESCRIPTION]',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") || message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS") || Client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag === 'Mr Tophat#3864').id){
            if(!member){
                message.channel.send("Please specify a member to kick");
            }
            else if(member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")){
                message.channel.send("You can't an admin");
            }
            else{
                if(member){
                    const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
                    memberTarget.kick();
                    message.channel.send("User has been kicked!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access `permissions` off a `User`. [What's the difference between a User and a GuildMember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Comment: i just did a simple fix, since that is the only time i get an error, i just made it so when i do get that error it sends a message saying you cant kick an admin

Comment: The simple fix is to change `message.mentions.users.first()` to `message.mentions.members.first()` as mentioned in the post I linked. This way `member` will *actually* be a `GuildMember` and you won't get any error.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to access `permissions` of a `user` instead of a `guildMember`. Declare your `member` like this:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

The difference is, that a `user` is the **global** discord `user` and a `guildMember` is the `user` on a specific `server`

---

#### Reference

- [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)