# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'highest' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot, and I want to make a command that adds the specified role to the specified user. The code executes well, but when I try to execute the command, it shows the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'highest' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/commands/moderation/addrole.js:16:22)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/index.js:57:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
(node:4928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The code for "addrole.js" in which the error occurs is

```
if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position)
      return message.channel.send('You cannot add a role to someone with an equal or higher role');
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening? For the full code go [here](https://replit.com/@Unknown1789/Discord-Bot#commands/moderation/addrole.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) returns a collection of `User`s and `User`s don't have roles. Only `GuildMember`s have. While a `User` is a global user on Discord, a `GuildMember` is a user on a specific server and this member has roles on that server.

So, instead of `message.mentions.users` you should use [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members)  that returns a collection of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is self-explanatory in the message.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'highest' of undefined`

The property `highest` is attempted to be accessed on `undefined` (which has no such property).

From your code `member.roles.highest.position` is accessed. From this, we can conclude `member.roles` is, in the case of your execution of the code, `undefined`.

Comment: Couldn't it also be `message.member.roles` which is undefined?

Comment: Yeah, I know what it means, but how do I fix the error? How do i make member.roles defined? I defined "member" as ``` const member = message.mentions.users.first(); ``` and roles as ``` const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]);``` .