# How to detect if a pinged user has a certain role?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm creating a command in which I need to send a specific message when the user pinged in the command has a certain role. The only thing I could come up with was this:

```
if(message.mentions.users.first().roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin" || "Mod")) {
            message.channel.send('This user has a role!')  
        }
```

I'm stuck in place and can't find a way to deal with it. The answer is probably obvious but with my JavaScript skills, I'm getting more and more frustrated with every change I make.

Also, this is the error that I get: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"

Comment: `message.mentions.users.first().roles` is `undefined` (hence the `cache` property cannot be read) so I'd suggest starting there to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Your mention accesses a *User* object, which is a global Discord User Representation. You want the *Member* object - which is a per server user representation - instead.

```
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

// Use Array#includes for cleaner syntax
if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.some(role => ["Admin", "Mod"].includes(role.name)) {
   message.channel.send('This member has a role!')  
}
```

Refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979077/12464931) for more information on User vs Member

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and saves up a lot of space

Comment: If my answer helped feel free to click the check mark to the left of my answer :v

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `||` operator on literals like that, only on booleans.

```
if(message.mentions.users.first().roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin" || r.name === "Mod")) {
        message.channel.send('This user has a role!')  
}
```

What actually happens in `r.name === "Admin" || "Mod"` is that `r.name === "Admin"` evaluates first to `true` or `false` depending on `r.name` value. Then in `true || "Mod"` or `false || "Mod"` `"Mod"` string is cast to a boolean (`true` for non-empty strings) so you get `true || true` or `false || true` which always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: That's not the problem here. I want to check if the user has at leas one of the mentioned roles. Also, the problem is with ```message.mentions.users.first().roles.cache.some``` not ```r => r.name === "Admin" || "Mod"```. The exact error says "Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"

Comment: Ah, you could have mentioned the error inside the question; nevertheless you'll have to fix this one ^^^ too to make it work.

Comment: I used my version inside a different command and it works perfectly, so I don't think I need to change it :)

Comment: I think your intension is to evaluate condition to true only if the user has Admin or Mod role. This condition `r => r.name === "Admin" || "Mod"` will evaluate to true always, even if user isn't Admin nor Mod.

Comment: User's do not have roles, members do