# Discord.js | Add a role with a reaction

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I've been on my discord bot for several days because I encountered a problem ...

I wanted to add the possibility of having a role following a reaction.

But it doesn't work as soon as I add the line to add the role, if I remove it it works fine.

code :

```
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, member) => {

    if(reaction.message.id === "894623823855493171"){

        member.roles.add('892423129345978438');
        reaction.message.channel.send(`Tu as réagi : ✅ ${member}`);

    }
       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`member` is actually a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). The better way to do this is to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) from the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). You can use [`GuildMemberManager.resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=resolve)

```js
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if(reaction.message.id === "894623823855493171"){
    const member = reaction.guild.members.resolve(user)
    member.roles.add('892423129345978438');
    reaction.message.channel.send(`Tu as réagi : ✅ ${member}`);
  }
})
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js) for more info