# How can a bot add roles to a user? (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I have a discord bot that I'm attempting to assign a user a role with. From some searching around, I've discovered that the code
`let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("[role_id]")`
`message.author.roles.add(role)`
is supposed to work.

The issue is that message.author.roles doesn't exist. Is there a new way to do this for discord.js v13, or am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 3):

As per the discord.js docs, [`Message#author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object, which doesn't have the `.roles` property. What you want is [`Message#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), which is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and has the property you want in order to give and remove roles.

Give this a shot:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("[role_id]")
message.member.roles.add(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use another method and it works as good as this, try it out

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "[role name here]")
message.member.roles.add(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mention = (await message.mentions.members.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find((r) => r.user.username.toLowerCase().includes() === args.join(" ").toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find((r) => r.displayName.toLowerCase().includes() === args.join(" ").toLocaleLowerCase()); // get member on mention
const role = message.mentions.roles.first(); // get role on mention
await mention.roles.add(role)
```

{prefix} {command} {mention a user} {mention a role}

Don't forget, this is in async function