# Add role to user by ID

Tags: discord.js

I try to add a role to a user by ID, but I always receive this error

```
user.roles.add(role)
                                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
```

Here is my code

```
let role = Guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === dataobj.Guild.name);

client.users.fetch(useritem).then((user) => {
     user.roles.add(role)
    .catch(error => { })
});
```

`dataobj.Guild.name` is the name of the role.
`useritem` is the ID of the user.

var `role` is correct and output the right role.
Var `user` is correct and output the right user.

I tried many things, but nothing works.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch `guild.members` instead of `client.users` and to add role by its ID you should use `role.id` instead of `role`