# Unable to get users .joinedAt value

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to write an `info` command. I don't think I'm correctly getting the guild member to get the .joinedAt value, and I haven't been able to find a recent example. Here is the relevant code. Any help appreciated:

```
const user = await interaction.options.getUser("user").fetch(true);
embed.setTitle(`User info for ${user.username}`);
embed.addFields(
  { name: "User Tag:", value: `${user.tag}`, inline: true },
  { name: "User ID:", value: `${user.id}`, inline: true },
  { name: "Bot Status:", value: `${user.bot}`, inline: true },
  {
    name: "Account Creation Date:",
    value: `${user.createdAt}`,
    inline: false
  },
  // I'm trying to get the .joinedAt value here
  {
    name: "Guild Join Date:",
    value: `${interaction.message.guild.member(user).joinedAt}`,
    inline: false
  }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting just common user using `getUser` instead of `getMember` which is server member