# DISCORD.JS V13 TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a bot discord, I was trying to check if member mentioned has permissions
but I have this problem:

```
if(member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply({content: ["no"]})
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
```

this is my code:

```
const { Client, Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "user",
    description: "comando a risposta",
    aliases: ["boop", "test"],
    /** 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply({content: ["he has the admin"]})
        message.reply(`${member.tag}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object which doesn't have `.permissions`. Get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object instead with `message.mentions.members.first()`

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
```

`User`s are not the same as `GuildMember`s: See [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63979076)

Comment: thx now is working!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so essentially this message is saying that discord.js is not recognising that a user has been mentioned in the message. The `.first()` methods returns `undefined` if the users collection is empty. So I recommend handling member possibly being undefined if no one has been mentioned in the message.

```
const member = message.mentions.users.first();

if (member === undefined) return message.reply({ content: "no user mentioned" })

if (member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
    return message.reply({ content: "user has the admin" })
message.reply({ content: `${member.tag}` });
```

Comment: yes now its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Client, Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "user",
    description: "comando a risposta",
    aliases: ["boop", "test"],
    /** 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first()
        if(member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            message.reply(`${member.tag} ha l'admin`)
        }
        if(!member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            message.reply(`${member.tag} non ha l'admin`)
        }
    }
```