# Joinedat difficulties discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to make an User Info command and I'm currently trying to add the function `User joined Discord at` but with the current code I only get my exact time when I execute the command [(see this link)](https://gyazo.com/ee8ebd752f6d9bc3025f135f436ed42a) and I don't know what to change in that command so it would work.

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) package for the date.

```js
            case 'minfo':

            const moment = require('moment')
  
            const membed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .addFields(
                {name: 'User Name:', value: `${message.author}`},
                {name: 'User ID:', value: `${message.author.id}`},
                {name: 'Joined at', value: `${moment(message.author.joinedat).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}`}
            )

            message.channel.send({embeds: [membed]})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message#author` is a `User`. `.joinedAt` only exists on `GuildMember`s which you can get with `Message#member`

```js
{name: 'Joined at', value: `${moment(message.member.joinedAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')} //remember capitalization
```

Additionally, `.createdAt` only exists on `User`s, not `GuildMember`s

Comment: Thank you that helped! but I also want to show the User when he joined Discord. Can i even script that?

Comment: `message.author.createdAt` as shown there