# Discord.js welcomer bot recieving users name as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a welcomer bot, it all works but for some reason, the user who joined's name is `undefined`. Here's the code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (joinMember) => {
    const joinChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '931712815637602331')
    let joinEmbed = {
        title : `Welcome to ${joinMember.guild.name}, @${joinMember.tag}`,
        color : embedColor
    }
    joinChannel.send({embeds : [joinEmbed]})
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 2):

`joinMember` is a `GuildMember` and it doesn't have a `tag` property. It does have a `user` property though and `User`s have [`tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag)s, so you can use `joinMember.user.tag`:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (joinMember) => {
  const joinChannel = client.channels.cache.get('931712815637602331');
  let joinEmbed = {
    title: `Welcome to ${joinMember.guild.name}, @${joinMember.user.tag}`,
    color: embedColor,
  };
  joinChannel.send({ embeds: [joinEmbed] });
});
```