# Assigning a Role by name to a User by ID in Discord.js version 14 gives a TypeError

Tags: discord.js

I have a member ID and a role name, and I want to give them the role:

Here is how I get a member by their ID:

```
let userid = '1234567890123456';
let member = await client.users.fetch(userid);
```

Here is how I get the guild object by ID:

```
let serverid = '1234567890123456';
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(serverid);
```

Here is how I get the role from the guild object by name:

```
let rolename = 'New Member';
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === rolename);
```

Up to here I can console.log member, guild, and role, and as far as I understand I'm seeing a member, a guild, and a role.

Now the part where my misunderstanding manifests:

```
member.roles.add(role);
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
```

I've seen this exact line of code on a dozen websites, so it MUST be correct. Working backwards, what's different? The other examples involve Interaction, whereas I'm fetching the member from the client by their ID, so it MUST have something to do with that. But what?

Answer (score 0):

The correct question turned out to be "What is the difference between a User and a Member?" This post explains it in more detail: [What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember-in-discord-js)

In short, Interactions contain a guild member, which belongs to a channel and can have roles, whereas the client provides a discord user, which cannot be given roles. They each represent the individual, but in a different context.

Here's the correct code:

```
let serverid = '1234567890123456789';
let userid = '1234567890123456789';
let rolename = 'New Member';
// use the server ID to get the guild object
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(serverid);
// make the GUILD (not the client) fetch the user id. you get a MEMBER now.
let member = await guild.members.fetch(userid);
// look up the role by name
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === rolename);
// add the role to the member
member.roles.add(role);
```

I'm posting this since I sunk about 3 hours into it.

Comment: We're glad you found the solution. However, answers on Stack Overflow should be to the point. The link you cited, along with your code and a brief explanation of how the solution works would be a better overall answer

Comment: Additionally, please do not add "(SOLVED)" or similar wording to your question title. Once a certain amount of time passes (usually a few days), you'll be able to accept your own answer, which will make it appear as solved.